# DTO and ViewBag issue MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, dto

Hi i have a problem getting data from two sources and combining into one DTO and then sending to the View

I have a list of Users in my Database and i have a list of Jobs in my WCF Service.  What i am trying to do is make an Add Job page where i get all of the Users current Jobs from the Database and make a new DropDown list in the View that display all the Jobs a user doesnt have.  So i intersect the two lists and create a new list with all obtained job removed.

I have tried doing it but cannot see where im going wrong.

```
public ActionResult AddJob(String usrCode)
{
    var jobs = jobClient.getAllJobs();
    var allJobCodes = (from s in jobs select s.jobCode).ToList();
    var thisJobCode = (from s in db.UserJobs
                               where s.usrCode == usrCode
                               select s.jobCode).ToList(); 
    var notObtained = allJobCodes.Except(thisJobCode);

    IEnumerable<String> list1 = allJobCodes.AsEnumerable();
    IEnumerable<String> list2 = notObtained.AsEnumerable();
    IEnumerable<String> list3 = list2.Select(x => new UserJobsDTO() 
                        { jobCode = x });

    IEnumerable<UserJobsDTO> list = list3(jobs, notObtained);
    ViewBag.jobCode = new SelectList(list, "jobCode", "Description");
    var model = new UserJobsDTO { usrCode = usrCode,  jobCode = list};

    return View("AddJob", model);
}


public class UserJobsDTO
{
    public string usrCode { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<String> jobCode { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone help me out?  The main problems at the moment are with jobCode = x  complaining about....

```
 Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type
'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'
```

And list3 variable complaining about this....

```
Error 2 'list3' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'
```

Answer (score 3):

The errors state exactly what the problems are...

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

Job code is a collection:

```
public IEnumerable<String> jobCode { get; set; }
```

But you're trying to assign a non-collection value to it:

```
list2.Select(x => new UserJobsDTO() 
                    { jobCode = x })
```

So either you need to make `jobCode` a string (such that any given instance of the DTO has one value) or set the entire collection to it (such that any given instance of the DTO has the list of values).

---

> 'list3' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'

I literally have no idea what you're even trying to do here:

```
IEnumerable<UserJobsDTO> list = list3(jobs, notObtained);
```

But, as the error states, `list3` is a variable not a method.  You can't *invoke* a variable like a method.

---

It's *very confusing* what you're trying to accomplish in this code.  And, honestly, the best advice at this time would just be to step through in a debugger, examine the runtime values that you have, and really think about how to structure those values for your view.

In particular, it will be *very* helpful to semantically discern between singular values and plural values.  For example, terms like `UserJobsDTO` or `jobCode` imply certain levels of singularity and plurality, but their types and structures don't agree with that.  (How can a *collection* of strings be a single "code"?)

Just the names and types of the structures you're using are *very important* in being able to logically understand and express what you're trying to do.